# How to convert HTML containing Java into PDF using iText?

Tags: java, html, pdf, text-files

I want to generate a PDF from HTML. HTML code having some of Java code which retrieves the values from one POJO class. This HTML Code is stored in a text file. I am unable to generate the desired PDF.

If I pass this HTML code as a string then I am able to generate the PDF.

Is there any way to generate PDF by reading HTML contents from file having Java code?

HTML file: `OwnerDetails.text`

```html
<html>
<body>
<table width="100%" style="background-color: skyblue;" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td align="center"> Owner Details </td>
        <td >invoiceDetails.getOwnerDetails().getOwnerName()</td>
    </tr>                
</table>            
</body>
</html>
```

In the code above, `invoiceDetails.getOwnerDetails().getOwnerName()` does not give the value; code prints as it is in the PDF.

Java Code:

```
public void generatepdfUsingst(InvoiceDetailsEntity invoiceDetails) {
    Document document  = new Document(PageSize.A4, 5, 5, 5, 5); 

    StringBuffer st = new StringBuffer();
    st.append("<html><body> This is HMTL to PDF conversion Example<table border='2' align='center'> <tr><td>");

    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\OwnerDetails.text"))) {  

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("E:\\pdffile.pdf"));
        document.open();

            while((line = br.readLine())!= null) {
                st.append( line);
            }


          st.append("</td></tr></table></body></html>");

        java.io.InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(st.toString().getBytes());
        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is);
        writer.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: You could set a variable to that value and then extract the value and print it. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `<td >invoiceDetails.getOwnerDetails().getOwnerName()</td>` doesn't look like Java code in HTML to me. A JSP/Servlet would have different format. Possibly it is **Javascript** code.

Comment: @the_ritz  i just want to read a file which has html tags and java code to populate the value of `owner name`.  At run time i want the value of 'owner name'  by 
 `invoiceDetails.getOwnerDetails().getOwnerName()` code

Comment: @suhas_n You can't print values within the code itself if that's what you mean.  Use java string manipulation to remove the code, and replace it with the value. You'll still have to extract that value from HTML though.

Comment: @AndrewThompson i am  reading the file in  `generatepdfUsingst(InvoiceDetailsEntity invoiceDetails)` method. So owner name which in inside the object that should get populate for `invoiceDetails.getOwnerDetails().getOwnerName()`

Comment: @the_ritz how to do this?